# java.net.UnknownHostException: smtps.aruba.it

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, centos7, unknown-host, aruba

I'm using javax.mail with a mail aruba account.

On a windows and a centos7 machine everything works.
But on another, specific, centos7 machine (under [aruba](https://www.aruba.it/home.aspx) server) tomcat7's console says:

[image]

I saw every posts that google and stackoverflow suggests to me, but nothing worked.

I think it's a machine enviroment problem.

**Mail class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
     @Service("mailSender")
    public class ApplicationMailer {

        private static javax.mail.Session session=null; 
        private static Resource resource = new ClassPathResou

rce("resources/mail.properties");

    static {
        try {
            final Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
            if (props!=null)
            {
                session = javax.mail.Session
                    .getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(props.getProperty("email.username"),
                                    props.getProperty("email.password"));
                        }

                    });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            session=null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;


    public MailSender getMailSender() {
        return mailSender;
    }

    public void setMailSender(MailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    /**
     * This method will send compose and send the message 
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws MessagingException 
     * @throws AddressException 
     * */
    public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String body) throws IOException, AddressException, MessagingException{
            Message mail = new MimeMessage(session);
            final Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
            mail.setFrom(new InternetAddress(props.getProperty("mail.from")));
            mail.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            mail.setSubject(subject);
            mail.setContent(body, "text/html");
            Transport.send(mail); 

    }
}
```

**mail.properties**

```
mail.debug=true
mail.from=*****
email.username=******
email.password=******

mail.smtp.host=smtps.aruba.it
mail.smtp.port=465
mail.smtp.localhost=localhost
mail.mime.charset=UTF-8
mail.smtp.auth=true

mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
mail.transport.protocol=smtps
```

**dispacer servlet**

```
  <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtps.aruba.it" />
        <property name="port" value="465" />
        <property name="protocol" value="smtps" />
        <property name="username" value="*****" />
        <property name="password" value="*****" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtps</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.localhost">localhost</prop>
                <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
<!--                <prop key="mail.smtps.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop> -->
                <prop key="mail.smtps.ssl.enable">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Try the [JavaMail connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug) on the server.  Possibly the name service isn't configured correctly on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. An `UnknownHostException` is thrown if the server name can't be resolved to an IP-address. This is most likely not a Java- or JavaMail issue but one concerning the configuration of the underlying operating system.

To be sure you can open a shell session and type one of the following

> host smtps.aruba.it
>
> dig smtps.aruba.it
>
> nslookup smtps.aruba.it

(dependent on what's installed, one or more commands might not exist)

If the answer is that the host is not known, you can stop troubleshooting your java application ;-)

Comment: Perfect, you right! it's  a machine enviroment problem.
I write in the terminal: `ping smtps.aruba.it` and it says **unknown host**.

SO HOW CAN I RESOLVE THAT?

Comment: DNS-configuration is part of the operating system so there is no answer I can give you here but there should be plenty of search results if you enter DNS configuration [your operating system] into the search engine of your choice. Since I answered your question, you might consider accepting it ;-)